Find roots for complicated expression involving HarmonicNumber
I have a equation like this:
(u + v + w + 2 u w + 2 v w + 2u v + 3u v w)/[1 - (v w +  uv + uw + 2 u v w)]
 u := Sum[ Exp[n k^2 - A k^2 HarmonicNumber[n]] ((1 - r)/(2 z))^n , {n, 
  1, \[Infinity]}]
 w := Sum[ Exp[n k^2 + B k HarmonicNumber[n]] ((1 - r)/(2 z))^n , {n, 
  1, \[Infinity]}]
 v := r/(z-r)


The coefficients A,B and r are numerical values in this problem and z changes over k. I replaced these three functions in my equation.
The convergence of this equation is important for me. I set the denominator's output equal to zero to find the roots that cause divergence.By changing the value of k, z changes. Ultimately, I want to plot Log[z] for different values of k. this is my code that I wrote in Mathematica, but it seems that root finding is not performed correctly.
 Clear[A, B, r, k, z]
A = 0.3;
B = 5;
r = 0.6;
f[k_ ] := 
 Log[z] /. 
  FindRoot[
   r/(-r + z)
       Sum[ Exp[n k^2 + B k HarmonicNumber[n]] ((1 - r)/(2 z))^
        n , {n, 1, \[Infinity]}] + (r/(-r + z) + 
        Sum[ Exp[n k^2 + B k HarmonicNumber[n]] ((1 - r)/(2 z))^
          n , {n, 1, \[Infinity]}] + (
        2 r Sum[ 
          Exp[n k^2 + B k HarmonicNumber[n]] ((1 - r)/(2 z))^n , {n,
            1, \[Infinity]}])/(-r + z)) Sum[ 
       Exp[n k^2 - A k^2 HarmonicNumber[n]] ((1 - r)/(2 z))^n , {n, 
        1, \[Infinity]}] == 1, {z, 1.}]
t1 = Table[{k, f[k]}, {k, -1.25, 1.2, 0.1}]
t2 = Table[{k, Log[Exp[k^2] ((1 - r)/2)]}, {k, -3, 3, 0.1}]; 


Show[{ListPlot[{t1, t2}, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> { "t1", "t2"}, PlotRange -> All]}]


and it's the my code output:
{{-1.25, 0.276179}, {-1.15, 0.16407}, {-1.05, 0.0761298}, {-0.95, 
  0.0070751}, {-0.85, -0.0469089}, {-0.75, -0.0884633}, {-0.65, \
-0.119248}, {-0.55, -0.140011}, {-0.45, -0.150528}, {-0.35, \
-0.149417}, {-0.25, -0.133874}, {-0.15, -0.0995016}, {-0.05, \
-0.0405739}, {0.05, 0.0488789}, {0.15, 0.173384}, {0.25, 
  0.334749}, {0.35, 0.532072}, {0.45, 0.762756}, {0.55, 
  1.02364}, {0.65, 1.31173}, {0.75, 1.62454}, {0.85, 1.96016}, {0.95, 
  2.31723}, {1.05, 2.69488}, {1.15, 3.09264}}

and plot:

The orange curve should intersect the blue curve, but when the value of k increases, it leades to divergence and results in an error. What's wrong with my code?

your problen seems to be related to the convergence of your equation and the root-finding process in Mathematica

Hi. yes, and how can I solve my problem? I think Mathematica can't find true root
